# Javascript + CSS : Dúvida sobre Value ou textContent

Tags: javascript, html

Fiz uma condição que não está respeitando o conteúdo do `text`. 
Segue o código:

```js
function teste() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("testetxt");
  if (elements.value =! null) {                  
    elements.style.border = 'solid 1px #00FF00;';
    alert("Ok");
  } else if (elements.value == null){
    elements.style.border = 'solid 1px #FF0000;';
    alert("Preencha o campo Código");
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <input class="testetxt" type="text"/>
    <button onclick="teste();" style="height:20px; width:20px;"> </button>
  </body>
</html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Há vários problemas no seu código além das que o @Marcos Brinner citou.

Um deles é o valor do style, que não pode ter o ponto-e-vírgula:

```
                                       errado!
                                          ↓
elements.style.border = 'solid 1px #00FF00;';
```

O `;` dentro das aspas invalida o valor do `style` e não fará efeito algum.

Outro problema é a forma de selecionar os elementos pela classe:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("testetxt");
```

Isso retorna uma coleção de nós com a classe `.testetxt` e não 1 elemento em si. Neste caso, se você quer selecionar o primeiro elemento com essa classe, o teria que adicionar o índice `[0]` na variável `elements`:

```
elements[0]
```

Outra coisa é que você pode omitir o `!= null`, deixando apenas if `(elements[0].value) {`.

Veja o código corrigido:

```js
function teste() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("testetxt");
  if (elements[0].value) {                  
    elements[0].style.border = 'solid 1px #00FF00';
    alert("Ok");
  } else {
    elements[0].style.border = 'solid 1px #FF0000';
    alert("Preencha o campo Código");
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="testetxt" type="text"/>
<button onclick="teste();" style="height:20px; width:20px;"> </button>
```

Comment: Entendi, neste caso teria de ser pelo ClassName para testar uma coisa, pois ele era elemento único e não teria necessidade de colocar um array, mas entendi os erros, valeu dvd <3

Answer (score 1):

No seu script tem um erro
você está usando  =! ao invez de != e está fazendo uma comparação redundante

```
function teste() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("testetxt");
  if (elements.value != null && elements.value !="") {                  
    elements.style.border = 'solid 1px #00FF00;';
    alert("Ok");
  } else{
    elements.style.border = 'solid 1px #FF0000;';
    alert("Preencha o campo Código");
  }
}
```

Comment: MEU DEUS, desculpe a minha burrice ;s
Valeu pela ajuda Marcos !!

Comment: rsrs td bem, as  vezes fico  horas tentando  achar  o  erro  e era apenas  um  ponto  e virgula